# CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment Dateformat - Android

Tags: android

I choose the date as in the photo. Released 19 Jul. While it should be 2020. I am printing out January 01, 2020. I have to print out the day, month and year separately, so I assigned them all to different variables. I can't print the date I selected. What is the problem?

```
 @Override
    public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"));
            SimpleDateFormat dateAy = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"));
            SimpleDateFormat dateGUN = new SimpleDateFormat("DD", Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"));

            String asWeek = dateFormat.format(dayOfMonth);
            String dateAyIsım = dateAy.format(monthOfYear);
            String dateGUNSIFIR = dateGUN.format(dayOfMonth);
```

[image]

Comment: Hey there can you please include what error you're getting while printing ?

Comment: I have to print 19 JUL 2020, while I am printing 01 January 2020

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormatSymbols` to get the month name from integer

```
DateFormatSymbols  dateFormatSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols().getInstance();
String month = dateFormatSymbols.getMonths()[monthOfYear-1];
```

for the day you can use `dayOfMonth` direct

as `format()` need as a date object, not an integer

Comment: I want to use data from CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment

Comment: in `onDateSet` function you have ` int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth`.  just replace `SimpleDateFormat` with `DateFormatSymbols`